# How to tranlsate these few strategy lines into study lines (usable in alerts)

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v4, pine-script-v5

I have been trying to translate a strategy into study (for alerts), but I'm stuck with these few lines :

```
longStop := strategy.position_size <= 0 ? longCondition ? tempStopLong : na : longStop[1]
longProfit := strategy.position_size <= 0 ? longCondition ? tempProfitLong : na : longProfit[1]
shortStop := strategy.position_size >= 0 ? shortCondition ? tempStopShort : na : shortStop[1]
shortProfit := strategy.position_size >= 0 ? shortCondition ? tempProfitShort : na : shortProfit[1]
```

They are used for exiting a position.
I would be really grateful if somebody could help me with that !
It's from an open source code, here is the full code if the context could help : https://www.tradingview.com/script/FUnOi1Nx-3x-SuperTrend-Strategy-Mel0nTek-V1/

Thanks !

Comment: Strategies support alerts now, either based on order fills (i.e. the alert triggers every time the strat fills any of its orders) or based on the calls of the `alert()` function (not to be confused with `alertcondition()`). It would probably be easier for you to use this instead of rewriting the strategy position logic to `study()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need two variables like `isLong` and `isShort` to figure out whether you are long or short. Then you can replace `strategy.position_size >= 0` with `isLong` and `strategy.position_size <= 0` with `isShort`.